# Can recursively calling an async await function to stack or memory problems?

Tags: javascript, websocket, async-await

I just started to use async-await and I'm wondering if you can call an async function recursively without getting into trouble.

I'm opening a Websocket connection from within an init function. In my real program the init function is more complex and contains a bunch of functions that need to be run in the correct order (like setting up database connections, etc). So the async-await provides a clean way of doing this.

When the Websocket connection is lost, I want to reestablish the connection. I do this by calling the function from within the function itself.

Will this way of doing it lead to any problems?
Or should I handle the promise in the recursive call or call it with return?

I did some searching but could not find a clear answer.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const token = '1234'
const hostname = 'ws://localhost:3000'

const createSocket = async () => {
  let socket = new WebSocket(hostname)

  socket.onopen = () => {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({'authorize': token}), (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(`${new Date().toUTCString()}: Socket Error while sending Auth`, error)
        Promise.reject(error)
      } else {
        Promise.resolve(socket)
      }
    })
  }

  socket.onclose = () => {
    console.log(`${new Date().toUTCString()}: Socket closed. Reopening`)
    socket = null
    setTimeout(createSocket, 200)
  }
}

const init = async () => {
  await createSocket()
}

init()
```

Comment: I don't think your code does anything close to what you expect ... what is `Promise.reject(...)` and `Promise.resolve(...)` .... besides "do nothing at all" code? ... "handle the promise" ... what promise?

Comment: @JaromandaX: The Resolve and Reject are the exits from the function. Otherwise the await in the init function would never resolve.

Comment: how is Promise.resolve and Promise.reject an "exit" from the `socket.send` callback ? you are wrong about the await never "resolving" ... `createSocket` is marked as `async`, therefore it returns a promise ... in this case, the promise will resolve to `undefined` as you have no return statement

Comment: `Promise.resolve` and `Promise.reject` are side-effect free (for all intents and purposes). They would not be exits from your function.